# The maximum notation as regards the absolute value?

Tags: matrices, functions, notation, definition, vectors

We know that $\max(\textbf{A})$ gives the maximum element of the array $\textbf{A}$. What is the notation, or a short formula, if we seek the element having the largest absolute value? e.g., $\textbf{Blah}(-10,3)=-10$.

Comment: $\max\{|\min A|, |\max A|\}$ looks neat but does not preserve the sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending Regret's suggestion:
\begin{equation}
\text{sign}(\frac{\min A + \max A}{2})\cdot\max\{|\min A|,|\max A|\}.
\end{equation}
This would not work if $|\min A| = |\max A| \neq 0$, in which case Blah(.,.) wouldn't be a function anyway (unless you arbitrarily choose one of the two possible answers).